# Google App Engine Go HTTP request to a slow page

Tags: http, google-app-engine, go

I want to make a HTTP request using Google App Engine in Go to a slow-responding website. My code is:

```
func request(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    c:=appengine.NewContext(r)
    client := urlfetch.Client(c)
    resp, err := client.Get("http://www.example.com")
    if err != nil {
        log.Print("err %s", err.String())
        return
    }
    ...}
```

After calling my website, I get such an error:

```
API error 1 (urlfetch: INVALID_URL): ApplicationError: 5 timed out
```

After looking a bi into it, I found some reference to [Transport class](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/go/urlfetch/reference.html) that allows to wait for HTTP requests for [up to 60 seconds](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/go/urlfetch/overview.html#Requests), but I can't find any description or example on how to make that work.

How can I make a HTTP request in GAE Go that will have a deadline longer than 5 seconds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend if possible, doing the urlfetch outside of your main request handler using [Tasks Queue API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/go/taskqueue/overview.html).

When constructing urlfetch.Transport, you should be able to override the default deadline like this:

```
t := urlfetch.Transport{Context:c, DeadlineSeconds: 5.0}
client := http.Client{Transport: &t}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remote sites are sometimes slow because of DNS resolution. Using the IP address might help (resolve the target host before connecting to http://a.b.c.d).

I don't know if Go lets you define a longer timeout value - what you can do is to poll several times until you get a reply (or have expired your retries count).

Good luck anyway.