# GAE Python URL Fetch throws InvalidURLError

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urllib2, urllib, urlfetch

GAE Python URL Fetch throws InvalidURLError while the same URL works perfectly with Postman ( Google Chrome App ).

**CODE**

```
url = "https://abcdefgh:28dfd95928dfd95928dfd95928dfd95928dfd95928dfd959@twilix.exotel.in/v1/Accounts/abcdefgh/Sms/send" 
form_fields = {
  "From": "08039511111",
  "To": "+919844100000",
  "Body": "message for you"
} 
form_data = urllib.urlencode (form_fields) 

try: 
  result = urlfetch.fetch(url=url,
                        payload=form_data,
                        method=urlfetch.POST,
                        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } 
  ) 
  logging.info ("result = ["+repr (result)+"] ") 
except Exception: 
  logging.error ("Exception. ["+traceback.format_exc ()+"] ")
```

**OUTPUT LOGS**

```
2016-01-21 15:48:23.368 +0530 E Exception. [ 
Traceback (most recent call last): File "main.py", line 27, in get method=urlfetch.POST, 
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/urlfetch.py", line 271, in fetch return rpc.get_result() 
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 613, in get_result return self.__get_result_hook(self) 
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/urlfetch.py", line 389, in _get_fetch_result 'Invalid request URL: ' + url + error_detail) InvalidURLError: Invalid request URL: https://abcdefgh:28dfd95928dfd95928dfd95928dfd95928dfd95928dfd959@twilix.exotel.in/v1/Accounts/abcdefgh/Sms/send ]
```

For security purpose, I have replaced sensitive text in the URL with similar different characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and the solution. 
We need to specify the HTTP auth info using headers.

```
        urlfetch.make_fetch_call (  rpc, 
                                    url, 
                                    method      = urlfetch.POST, 
                                    headers     = {     "Authorization"     : "Basic %s" % base64.b64encode ( URL_USERNAME+":"+URL_PASSOWRD ) }, 
        )
```

**Courtesy**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8454580/1443563 by [raugfer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1078623/raugfer)

Answer (score 0):

[The code](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/urlfetch.py?spec=svn490&r=490#384) indicates an `INVALID_URL` RPC error code was received from the urlfetch service.

The most common occurence seems to be due to the URL length limit (check if your unedited URL hits that): [Undocumented max length for urlfetch URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25420168/undocumented-max-length-for-urlfetch-url)

A long time ago it was also seen for very slow URLs (in `Go` land, but I suspect the urlfetch service itself is the same serving all language sandboxes) - unsure if this still stands, I also see a `DEADLINE_EXCEEDED` error code as well which *might* have been introduced specifically for such case in the meantime): [Google App Engine Go HTTP request to a slow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939614/google-app-engine-go-http-request-to-a-slow-page)

The failure *might* also be related to incorrect parsing of the rather unusual "host" portion of your URL `foo:blah@hostname`. Check if it you're getting the same error if dropping the `foo:blah@` portion. If it's indeed the case you might want to file an issue with Google - the URL *seems* valid, works with `curl` as well.

Comment: Thanks Dan. I found the problem and the solution. 
We need to specify the HTTP auth info using headers. 

urlfetch.make_fetch_call (  rpc, 
                                        url, 
                                        method      = urlfetch.POST, 
                                        headers     = {     "Authorization"     : "Basic %s" % base64.b64encode ( URL_USERNAME+":"+URL_PASSOWRD ) }, 
            )